# Is this double quotient of $\operatorname{SL}_2$ representable by an algebraic space or a scheme?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, representable-functors, algebraic-spaces

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$Let $B$ be a Borel subgroup (upper triangular matrices), and let $\Gamma := \langle \sigma\rangle$ be the group generated by a (hyperbolic) element of $\SL_2/\mathbb{Q}_p$ of infinite order. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the big Zariski site of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, and let $\Gamma\backslash{\SL_2}/B$ be the functor which sends a $\mathbb{Q}_p$ scheme $X$ to the set of double cosets $\Gamma\backslash{\SL_2(\mathcal{O}(X))}/B(\mathcal{O}(X))$, where $\mathcal{O}(X)$ is the ring of global sections on $X$.

Denote by $(\Gamma\backslash{\SL_2}/B)^+$ the sheafification of the functor $\Gamma\backslash{\SL_2}/B$.

My question is: is $(\Gamma\backslash{\SL_2}/B)^+$ representable by a scheme/algebraic space?

My trivial thoughts are: the sheafification of $\SL_2/B$ is the functor $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$. If there is a way of realizing $(\Gamma\backslash{\SL_2}/B)^+$ as the sheafification of $(\Gamma\backslash\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{Q}_p})$, then perhaps it is possible to realize this as a corollary to one of the theorems regarding the representability of the quotient of a scheme by a group.

Comment: It seems like, even if the answer is yes, it probably isn't what you want to ask. To take a simpler example, remove the two fixed points of $\sigma$ from $\mathbb{P}^1$, so what is left over is a copy of $\mathbb{G}_m$ on which $\sigma$ acts freely. The quotient $\mathbb{G}_m/\langle \sigma \rangle$ wants to be an elliptic curve. (For example, that's what it is as a complex manifold, if we are working over $\mathbb{C}$.) But I don't think that is what your sheafification description gives.

Comment: 1/2: What I am eventually interested in is understanding the ring of global sections on a stack of the form $\mathbb{A}^1\times [\Gamma\setminus SL_2/B]$. By definition, these are the global sections of the sheaf $Hom(\mathbb{A}^1\times [\Gamma\setminus SL_2/B], \mathbb{A}^1)$. Since the map between a presheaf and a sheaf factors through its sheafification, the former is isomorphic to $Hom(\mathbb{A}^1\times (\Gamma\setminus SL_2/B)^+, \mathbb{A}^1)$.

Comment: 2/2: I want to show that $Hom(\mathbb{A}^1\times (\Gamma\setminus SL_2/B)^+, \mathbb{A}^1)$ is isomorphic to the tensor product $Hom(\mathbb{A}^1, \mathbb{A}^1)\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}_p} Hom((\Gamma\setminus SL_2/B)^+, \mathbb{A}^1)$, but this is not true in the generality of sheaves, so I was hoping to try and show that $(\Gamma\setminus SL_2/B)^+$ is an algebraic space, so that maybe the claim I am trying to prove would have a better chance of being true in this generality.

Comment: TeX note: as the name suggests, `\setminus` is for set complements, and spaces accordingly.  For a literal backslash, use `\backslash`.  Non-obviously, this interacts poorly with the clever spacing tricks of defined operators, so you need to turn off that spacing with braces.  Compare $\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\Gamma\setminus\SL_2/B$ `\Gamma\setminus\SL_2/B`; $\Gamma\backslash\SL_2/B$ `\Gamma\backslash\SL_2/B`; $\Gamma\backslash{\SL_2}/B$ `\Gamma\backslash{\SL_2}/B`.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: What happened with that earlier "answer"?  Was that produced by a bot (as I suspected)?

Comment: Yes. How common is that on the stack exchange forum now days?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/443396/is-this-double-quotient-of-operatornamesl-2-representable-by-an-algebraic-s#comment1144750_443396), while not exactly an answer to your question, the issue has been discussed on [MMO](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5531/chatgpt-strikes-mathoverflow).